# .htaccess is not working on all links

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have two URL samples in my new site.

1. sample1: http://localhost/phone/3
2. sample2: http://localhost/phone/3/10

*please note: phone is the project name*

And I wrote an htaccess file myself, but it's only working with sample1.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?menu=$1 [L]
```

I need a version that works on both samples. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: No, I just gave up and doing old ugly way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /phone/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2 [L]
```

//OR the following if the values are always going to be integers (This is the best way)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /phone/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?\.js)$ /phone/js/$2 [L] #Makes JS static content work
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?\.css)$ /phone/css/$2 [L] #Makes CSS static content work
```

I wouldn't recommended using (.*?). Its best to be specific what you want the value to be.

Absolute paths would be better over static paths.

Static Path

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Absolute Path

```
<script src="http://localhost/phone/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If your worried and transportability you could create a settings file, with this in:

```
define("WWW_DOMAIN", "http://localhost/phone/");
```

Use this on the top of every page as:

And then do:

```
<script src="<?php echo WWW_DOMAIN;?>script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make a website easier to develop locally before moving it do a different server. Then all you have to do is change WWW_DOMAIN once.

Might be easier than doing it with htaccess.

Comment: It almost works. But in case of Sample2, site working without images, css files, js files.

Comment: Yeah I've just seen. Never worked with links how you have. I always have absolute paths.

Comment: For call page like `site/index.php?menu1&page2` i must do `<a href="1/2">` right?

Comment: It might be /phone/1/2/ (Locally anyway). Try and see.

Comment: if i upload all my project, can you see and help me?

Comment: Absolute paths might be the best way. For developing between local and main servers.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
RewriteRule phone/([^/]+)$ /index.php?menu=$1
RewriteRule phone/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?menu=$1&some=$2
```

Or if your params are always integers:

```
RewriteRule phone/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?menu=$1
RewriteRule phone/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?menu=$1&some=$2
```

Comment: Not working sorry. After put it my browser telling me below text. Can you post whole htaccess content? <br/><br/>

`code
Not Found

The requested URL /phone/2 was not found on this server.`

Comment: Right now i'm accessing my site `http://localhost/phone/`. After do it nothing works.

Comment: site works. but both case of sample1 and sample2, browser telling me `Not Found

The requested URL /phone/3 was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use ([^/]+) instead of (.*)

The difference is that ([^/]+) doesn't include forward slashes. (.*) fails when you have a url that ends with a slash. For example:

```
home/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1
```

will work perfectly for

```
sitename.com/home/contact
```

and

```
sitename.com/home/contact/
```

you'll get a $_GET['menu'] containing contact with both url. With (.*) the second one will contain contact/ so with a trailing forward slash.

ending with /?$ means that the trailing / is optional at the end.

Edit:

complete code in htaccess format:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^phone/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1
RewriteRule ^phone/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&var2=$2
```

Comment: Can you put it in htaccess style?

Comment: Here you go. I've changed my main post.

Comment: Can't access my site. Its telling me "not found"

Comment: I've just setup a local server for it. But I can't tell you where your error is. It works perfectly here.

Comment: Is it because of i access my site with "localhost/phone/" instead of /localhost/" ?

Comment: could be. I always use aliases and vhosts for different local sites.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?menu=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?menu=$1&some=$2
```

**UPDATED Again**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /phone
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Do not rewrite static files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # Do not rewrite static directories
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?menu=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?menu=$1&some=$2
```

Try this

Comment: I replaced with it. But all css, images are gone!

Comment: If you want to use only int values in string use ([0-9]+) not (.*)

Comment: did you add Options +FollowSymLinks and RewriteEngine On on the top?

Comment: Yes, now it's printing error. <pre>Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.</pre>

Comment: Not working on both case. Even can't access my site. Its telling "internal Server Error"

Comment: From last Apache error logs:
`
[Wed May 04 17:33:51 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/phone/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Wed May 04 17:33:51 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed May 04 17:33:54 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/phone/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Wed May 04 17:33:54 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico`

Comment: Try to add the rewrite base "RewriteBase /phones"

Comment: Aafter add "RewriteBase /phone", sample2 working without css,js,image files.

Comment: Well working after add /phone/ in path. But after put project in server, i need change all include paths. Isn't there other way?

Comment: maybe like this: RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.+)\.css$ /phone/styles/$1.css [NC] Please Try the same for img

Comment: good advice from my practice - use only url like /some/img.jpg - too much problems will be solved

Comment: not working `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.+)\.css$ /phone/styles/$1.css`

Comment: >>Well working after add /phone/ in path. But after put project in server, i need change all include paths. Isn't there other way? <br> I think that the solution is (using rewrite), but better to change the urls cause in future you may be forget some details of your project and you will be confused in old urls

Comment: no, like this <a href="/phone/1/12">Some</a>. If u put / at the start of url it means that the url start from domain name, not from current directory (start from http://domain.com)